# Mongoose Error when trying to load my model from a different file

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm getting an error for trying to include a mongoose model written in a separate file.

> throw new mongoose.Error.MissingSchemaError(name);
>
> MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Cart".
>   Use mongoose.model(name, schema)

Within my server.js file my mongo models are defined before I call my routes. Which I've looked around and found defining your models after the routes are the cause of this error but that's not my case.

```
//Require db config
require('./app_api/config/model.js');

//Require routes config
var routesAPI = require('./app_api/config/routes.js')

var app = express();
```

Within my model.js file I require my separate schemas.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var dbURI = 'mongodb://localhost/followdata';

mongoose.connect(dbURI);

// CONNECTION EVENTS
mongoose.connection.on('connected', function() {
  console.log('Mongoose connected to ' + dbURI);
});
mongoose.connection.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log('Mongoose connection error: ' + err);
});
mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function() {
  console.log('Mongoose disconnected');
});

// SCHEMA DECLERATION
require('../models/user');
require('../models/userCart');
```

So I'm not really sure what the problem is.

This is how I try to bring in my cart model into my user model schema.

```
var mongoose    = require( 'mongoose' );
var jwt         = require('jsonwebtoken');
var crypto      = require('crypto');
var Cart        = mongoose.model('Cart');

var Schema      = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({ ......... });
```

And within my userCart.js file I export it properly.

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Cart', cartSchema);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to require in your `Cart` schema if you want to use it in your User model schema.

So, you would need `var Cart = require('yourPathToCart/cart')` instead of `var Cart = mongoose.model('Cart')` (the previous line of code is attempting to create a new model named Cart and this is where your error is coming from) in your User model schema file.